# The variable changes inside of my loop, but stays the same in main code in React Native

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm declaring `k` before my loop like so:

```
let k = 7;
const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false);
```

I'm wanting to change the value of `k` to be whatever `i` is. It does so successfully:

(seriesList stores objects)

```
for (let i in seriesList) {
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => 
     {setModalOpen(true)
     k = i
     console.log("k inside loop:" + k)}}>
<Image style={externalStyle.image, {top: customTop, left: customLeft, right: customRight, height: 180, width: 200}} source={seriesList[i].uri}/> 
    </TouchableOpacity> 
                         }
```

However, when I try to use it in `<Modal>` in return, the value of `k` stays the same as what I declare it before the loop. This is the `<Modal>` code.

```
return(
<Modal visible={modalOpen} animationType='slide'>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => 
    {setModalOpen(false)
     console.log("k outside of loop: " + k)
    }}> 
     <Image 
     style={{ width: 50, height: 50, left: 20, bottom: -50}}
     source={require('../assets/removeblue.png')}/> 
 </TouchableOpacity> 

<Image style={{height: 200, width: 200,  bottom: -40, left: 105}} source={seriesList[k].uri}/>
 <Text
 style={{
 bottom: -60,
 color: 'black',
 fontFamily: 'MarkerFelt-Thin',
 fontSize: 21,
 textAlign: 'left'
          }}
Name:  {seriesList[k].name}</Text>
 <Text
 style={{
 bottom: -90,
 color: 'black',
 fontFamily: 'MarkerFelt-Thin',
 fontSize: 21,
 textAlign: 'left'
          }}
Year:  {seriesList[k].year}</Text>
 <Text
 style={{
 bottom: -120,
 color: 'black',
 fontSize: 21,
 textAlign: 'left',
 fontFamily: 'MarkerFelt-Thin'
         }}
Description:  {seriesList[k].description}</Text> 
</Modal> 
)
```

Does anyone know how to make sure the `k` in `<Modal>` does change for what's in the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that you've set `k = i` using the `onPress` callback of `TouchableOpacity`, but your `Modal` doesn't re-render since there was no state change. Try controlling `k` with state.

```
const [k, setK] = useState(7);
```

```
for (let i in seriesList) {
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
      setModalOpen(true);
      setK(i);
    }}>
       <Image style={externalStyle.image, {top: customTop, left: customLeft, right: customRight, height: 180, width: 200}} source={seriesList[i].uri}/> 
    </TouchableOpacity> 
}
```